# Sencha: building ExtJS project tries to find amd64 jvm on i386 machine

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I try to build an ExtJS app with Sencha on Windows (sencha app build comand in cmd).
Until today, everything was fine and working properly. 
Suddenly, this error shows:

```
D:\XXX\XXX>sencha app build
Error: could not open `C:\Windows\jre\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
```

The thing is, I'm on a i386 machine and I don't have an amd64 jvm. I shouldn't have it and I don't know  why all of a sudden Sencha thinks so. 
Reinstalling Sencha won't help.

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Did a file under /.sencha/ get changed? Check your version control history to see if another dev on your team accidentally mucked something.

Comment: No, as far as I can see, the only commit in that directory was the initial one. After that, nothing was changed

Comment: Does the file exist at that location? Also, what version of Windows are you running?

Comment: I am running Windows 7 professional, and there is no file at that location. There is, however, a file at `C:\Windows\jre\lib\i386\jvm.cfg', but when I try to copy it to a fake amd64 folder, it says: Error: loading: C:\Windows\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll; Error: loading: C:\Windows\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll

Comment: If there's no larger stack trace, the only thing I can recommend is a full uninstall - followed by a full reinstall. Clearly something got mucked internally, perhaps via a Java update or something.